# Meteor mupx ssl configuration is not working, still routing to port 80

Tags: javascript, ssl, meteor, docker

Heres my mup.json:

```
// Configure environment
  "env": {
    "PORT": 3000,
    "ROOT_URL": "https://www.exomatch.com"
  },
    //SSL 
   "ssl": {
    "certificate": "ssl/ssl.crt", // this is a bundle of certificates 
    "key": "ssl/private.key", // this is the private key of the certificate 
    "port": 443 // 443 is the default value and it's the standard HTTPS port 
  },
```

Here are the automatically generated docker container:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                    COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                        NAMES
454d0d829b8b        meteorhacks/mup-frontend-server:latest   "/start.sh"            9 minutes ago       Up 9 minutes        0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp         exomatch-frontend
71398a208be1        meteorhacks/meteord:base                 "/bin/sh -c 'bash $M   9 minutes ago       Up 9 minutes        0.0.0.0:3000->80/tcp         exomatch
f39a9105b72f        mongo:latest                             "/entrypoint.sh mong   39 hours ago        Up 39 hours         127.0.0.1:27017->27017/tcp   mongodb
```

I don´t get it... when i visit the website under the port 443 i don´t get an answer from the server either. The rest of mupx is configured correctly (deployment works!), also i ran mupx setup and mupx deploy.

The directory structure of the application is the following:

```
/// ROOT
- client
  ----views
      --- application, admin, usw...   
- collections
- lib 
- packages
- private
- public
- server
      ---- Methods hooks usw...
- ssl
 -----private.key; ssl.crt
- mup.json
- packages.json
- settings.json
- smart.json
- smart.lock
```

The Application is running on Amazon EC2 without a Loadbalancer.

Comment: Can you also post the mupx directory structure?

Comment: Yes for sure, i added more information including the application structure. Is the application structure what u wanted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're welcome! I initially forgot to post it here too.
We all need recognition when we can get it, thanks.

I found this quote somewhere, sounds like a starting point to check...I
n your EC2 control panel, look at your instance and note the Security Group that is assigned to it. Then, navigate to the Security Groups section in the control panel, open your group, and make sure that port 443 is allowed over TCP.

This must be open to allow SSL traffic to your instance. A simple way to check if the port is open to the outside is to telnet into your server's IP on port 443, and see if you can connect and get a response.